# EF CTP5 failing to update optional navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a many to one association between "Project" and "Template".

Project has a property of type "Template".

The association is not bidirectional ("Template" has no knowledge of "Project").

My entity mapping for the association on "Project" is:

```
this.HasOptional(p => p.Template);
```

If I create a "Project" without specifying a template then null is correctly inserted into the "TemplateId" column of the "Projects" table.

If I specify a template then the template's Id is correctly inserted. The SQL generated:

```
update [Projects]
set    [Description] = '' /* @0 */,
       [UpdatedOn] = '2011-01-16T14:30:58.00' /* @1 */,
       [ProjectTemplateId] = '5d2df249-7ac7-46f4-8e11-ad085c127e10' /* @2 */
where  (([Id] = '8c1b2d30-b83e-4229-b0c3-fed2e36bf396' /* @3 */)
        and [ProjectTemplateId] is null)
```

However, if I try to change the template or even set it to null, the templateId is not updated. The SQL generated:

```
update [Projects]
set    [UpdatedOn] = '2011-01-16T14:32:14.00' /* @0 */
where  ([Id] = '8c1b2d30-b83e-4229-b0c3-fed2e36bf396' /* @1 */)
```

As you can see, TemplateId is not updated.

This just does not make sense to me. I have even tried explicitly setting the "Template" property of "Project" to null in my code and when stepping through the code you can see it has absolutely no effect!

Thanks,
Ben

[Update]

Originally I thought this was caused by me forgetting to add the IDbSet property on my DbContext. However, now that I've tested it further I'm not so sure. Below is a complete test case:

```
public class PortfolioContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public PortfolioContext(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName) { }

    public IDbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BarMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Foos");
        this.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        this.HasOptional(f => f.Bar);
    }
}

public class BarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Bars");
        this.HasKey(b => b.Id);
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
[Test]  
public void Template_Test()
{
    var ctx = new PortfolioContext("Portfolio");

    var foo = new Foo { Name = "Foo" };
    var bar = new Bar { Name = "Bar" };

    foo.Bar = bar;

    ctx.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    object fooId = foo.Id;
    object barId = bar.Id;

    ctx.Dispose();

    var ctx2 = new PortfolioContext("Portfolio");
    var dbFoo = ctx2.Set<Foo>().Find(fooId);

    dbFoo.Bar = null; // does not update

    ctx2.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that this is using SQL CE 4.

Comment: Please post your object model as well as the code that doesn't work as expected so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: We cannot repro with a *"A simplified version of your model"*.

Comment: @Morteza, don't waste any time on this. I forgot to add the IDbSet<ProjectTemplate> property for ProjectTemplate to my DbContext. It was only when I started creating a complete example to demonstrate the "bug" (cough) that I spotted MY mistake.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Also that you've used inheritance in your model and it can behave totally different depend on the chosen strategy. Anyways, thanks for the update and I'm glad you solve the problem :)

Comment: @Morteza, unfortunately this was short lived. Although my initial tests worked, it did not accurately test what was happening in my web application (basically I am using a context per request). I have updated my post with a complete test case that replicates the issue. Many thanks for your time so far.

Comment: I just post an answer, see how this one works out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you just need to load the navigation property before doing anything to it. By loading it you essentially register it with ObjectStateManager which EF looks into to generate the update statement as a result of SaveChanges().

```
using (var context = new Context())
{                
    var dbFoo = context.Foos.Find(fooId);             
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.LoadProperty(dbFoo, f => f.Bar);

    dbFoo.Bar = null;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will result in:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Foos]
set [BarId] = null
where (([Id] = @0) and ([BarId] = @1))
',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier',@0='A0B9E718-DA54-4DB0-80DA-C7C004189EF8',@1='28525F74-5108-447F-8881-EB67CCA1E97F'
```

Comment: @Morteza, is it possible to do this with an Include expression. We use a generic repository and although I can create a specific implementation for projects, I still don't have direct access to the ObjectContext (we built a wrapper object around our context, IDbContext but we do have access to the IDbSets)

Comment: Yes of course. The only reason I used Load method was because you've used Find() method to load dbFoo and I wanted to change your code as least as possible.

Comment: @Morteza - I can confirm this works. Is this the intended behaviour for optional uni directional associations?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your associations being unidirectional or optional. Like I said, update statements is generated based on the CurrentValues that is being tracked by ObjectStateManager (OSM). If you don't load your navigation property, OSM has no track of it hence it will be ignored.

Comment: Could you make it general, for situations when you don't know the property already?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a bug in EF CTP5 (and not my code :p) there are two workarounds that I came up with.

1) Make the association Bi-Directional. In my case this meant adding the following to my ProjectTemplate class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get;set;}
```

With this done, in order to set the "Template" property of project to null, you can just remove the project from the template - a little backward but it works:

```
    var project = repo.GetById(id);
var template = project.Template;
template.Projects.Remove(project);
// save changes
```

2) The second option (which I preferred but it still smells) is to add the foreign key on your domain object. In my case I had to add the following to Project:

```
    public Guid? TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectTemplate Template { get; set; }
```

Make sure the Foreign key is a nullable type.

I then had to change my mapping like so:

```
this.HasOptional(p => p.Template)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(p => p.TemplateId);
```

Then, in order to set the Template to null, I added a helper method to Project (it does actually work just by setting the foreign key to null):

```
    public virtual void RemoveTemplate() {
        this.TemplateId = null;
        this.Template = null;
    }
```

I can't say that I'm happy about polluting my domain model with foreign keys but I couldn't find any alternatives.

Hope this helps.
Ben